# Creating a histogram in excel using m code / DAX

Tags: excel, statistics, dax, m, powerbi

I'm using this awesome [tutorial](https://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/2014/10/07/creating-histograms-with-power-query/).

```
let
    //Get data from Customers table
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Customers"]}[Content],
    //Get a list of all the values in the Age column
    Ages = Table.Column(Source,"Age"),
    //Find the maximum age
    MaxAge = List.Max(Ages),
    //The number of buckets is the max age divided by ten, then rounded up to the nearest integer
    NumberOfBuckets = Number.RoundUp(MaxAge/10),
    //Hash function to determine which bucket each customer goes into
    BucketHashFunction = (age) => Number.RoundDown(age/10),
    //Use Table.Partition() to split the table into multiple buckets
    CreateBuckets = Table.Partition(Source, "Age", NumberOfBuckets, BucketHashFunction),
    //Turn the resulting list into a table
    #"Table from List" = Table.FromList(CreateBuckets, Splitter.SplitByNothing()
                           , null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    //Add a zero-based index column
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Table from List", "Index", 0, 1),
    //Calculate the name of each bucket
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Bucket", 
                        each Number.ToText([Index]*10) & " to " & Number.ToText(([Index]+1)*10)),
    //Find the number of rows in each bucket - ie the count of customers
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Count", each Table.RowCount([Column1])),
    //Remove unnecessary columns
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Column1", "Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

The end result is:

[image]

**I would like to know how I can bucket all ages over 50 into a bucket called "50+"?**

Comment: http://www.daxpatterns.com/static-segmentation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the line:
BucketHashFunction = (age) => Number.RoundDown(age/10),

to something like:
BucketHashFunction = (age) => if(age > 85) then "85+" else Number.RoundDown(age/10),

You will also need to ensure data types are correct on this line:

## "Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Bucket",

```
                    each Number.ToText([Index]*10) & " to " & Number.ToText(([Index]+1)*10)),
```

Best to use the UI to set the data type to string. I didn't test this solution but that's essentially the pattern to follow.

Appreciate your using Power BI.

Lukasz P.

Power BI Team, Microsoft

If you'd like to stay up to date with the Power BI developer story updates you can register (http://solutions.powerbi.com/appsuggestion.html) or follow our blog (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbidev/)